# Função JavaScript que verifica se o scroll do textarea foi movido

Tags: javascript

Como fazer uma função JavaScript que verifica se o scroll de uma textarea (esse textarea possui um termo de responsabilidade) foi movido.

Se o usuário mover o scroll, habilitar uma `div` com a continuação de um formulario de cadastro.

Segue o código:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('id').onscroll = function(){
   alert('foi movido');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em Javascript puro

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById('id').onscroll = function(){
       alert('foi movido');
    }
}
```

Ou também você pode usar esse comando do [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)   - [`.scroll`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

```
$("#id").scroll(function() { alert('Foi movido') });
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Silvio Andorinha.

Comment: Ele não mencionou jquery, apenas javascript. Era interessante completar a sua resposta inserindo um exemplo com javascript puro.

Comment: @Filipe ok, estou fazendo uns testes aqui e já complemento a resposta

Comment: Sou zero em conhecimento de javascript. Aqui não deu certo

Comment: @Geraniel edite sua pergunta e poste o código da sua textarea por favor..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/an9Na/ da uma olhada aqui está funcionando.

Comment: @Geraniel editei a pergunta usando o `window.onload` faça o teste novamente

Comment: @Geraniel sim é por causa do `window.onload` faça o teste com a alteração que eu fiz na resposta.

Comment: show ficou tri http://jsfiddle.net/nF7Qm/ . Muito obrigado

Comment: @Geraniel fico feliz em ajudar, como você é novo no site te aconselho a dar uma olhada nessa [página](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @Geraniel e se a resposta te ajudou, por favor não esqueça de marca-la como certo ;)